# dvipdfm horizontally crops image

Tags: graphics, dvipdfmx

On windows 7 64bits with Miktex 2.9 `latex` compile correctly my document and DVI shows all images correctly. Then `dvipdfm` produces a correct PDF except for one image that is cropped horizontally. To reproduce download [the example](http://mariovalle.name/dvipdfm.zip) and then:

```
latex test.tex
yap test.dvi           # correct
dvipdfm test.dvi
AcroRd32.exe test.pdf  # cropped
```

Question: how to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! Some users are paranoid and would prefer not to download suspicious .zip files. If possible, you should reduce your .tex file to a minimal example showing the problem, and then include it in your question as a code snippet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The conversion from PostScript to PDF is configured in `dvipdfmx.cfg`:

> ```
> %% Ghostscript (PS-to-PDF and PDF-to-PDF):
> %%
> %% ps2pdf is a front-end to gs. For a complete list of options, see
> %% http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm#Options
> %%
> %% By default, gs encodes all images contained in a PS file using
> %% the lossy DCT (i.e., JPEG) filter. This often leads to inferior
> %% result (see the discussion at http://electron.mit.edu/~gsteele/pdf/).
> %% The "-dAutoFilterXXXImages" and "-dXXXImageFilter" options used
> %% below force all images to be encoded with the lossless Flate (zlib,
> %% same as PNG) filter. Note that if the PS file already contains DCT
> %% encoded images (which is possible in PS level 2), then these images
> %% will also be re-encoded using Flate. To turn the conversion off,
> %% simply remove the options mentioned above.
> %%
> %% Also note that PAPERSIZE=a0 is specified below. This converts PS
> %% files (including EPS) to A0 papersize PDF. This is necessary to
> %% prevent gs from clipping PS figure at some papersize. (A0 above
> %% simply means large size paper.) If you have figures even larger
> %% than A0, and their llx=lly=0, you can use "-dEPSCrop" instead of
> %% "-sPAPERSIZE=a0"
> %%
> %% In TeX Live, we use the rungs wrapper instead of ps2pdf, becuse we
> %% must omit the -dSAFER which ps2pdf specifies: in order for pstricks
> %% to work with xetex,
> %% /usr/local/texlive/*/texmf-dist/dvips/pstricks/pstricks.pro (for
> %% example) needs to be accessed.  (Also, it is better to use our
> %% supplied gs on Windows.)  You can also add -dNOSAFER to the ps2pdf
> %% command line.
> %%
> %% Incidentally, especially in TL, more than one dvipdfmx.cfg may be
> %% extant.  You can find the one that is active by running:
> %% kpsewhich -progname=dvipdfmx -format='other text files' dvipdfmx.cfg
> %%
> D  "rungs -q -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sPAPERSIZE=a0 -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=%v -dAutoFilterGrayImages=false -dGrayImageFilter=/FlateEncode -dAutoFilter ColorImages=false -dColorImageFilter=/FlateEncode -sOutputFile='%o' '%i' -c quit"
> ```

`figure02.eps` has size 3854bp x 1882bp that is larger than A0 with 841mm x 1189mm.

Thus you can use reconfigure using `-dEPSCrop` or convert the file manually to PDF:

```
ps2pdf -dEPSCrop figure02.eps
```

And run `ebb` to get a bounding box data file for driver `dvipdfmx` of LaTeX's `graphics` package:

```
ebb -x figure02.pdf
```

Then the image can be included as PDF file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=0.9\columnwidth,keepaspectratio=true]{figure02.pdf}

\end{document}
```

This also speeds up the compilation, because the EPS figure does not need to be converted each time running `dvipdfmx`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as SiliconValley but I was not allowed to use any additional latex packages and options. Therefore I could not apply Heiko's solution - which would be great otherwise.

If the height of the eps figure is less than the maximum width and the width of the eps figure is less than the maximum height, you rotate the eps figure during creation by 90 degree and rotate it -90 degree in the latex include command. Thus, the rotated eps file is included as follows in the tex file:

```
\includegraphics[width=6.2cm,angle=-90]{demo_rotated.eps}
```

Without rotating, it would have been included as

```
\includegraphics[width=6.2cm]{demo.eps}
```

*edit 2015-11-21:* 
There might be a situation in which you are not allowed to use the `graphicx` package with the option `dvipdfmx`. In my situation, I am writing an journal article for Atmospheric Chemistry and Physics and have to use the [Copernicus Publications LaTeX Package, version 3.8](http://www.atmospheric-chemistry-and-physics.net/Copernicus_LaTeX_Package.zip). The guidelines of using additional packages are quite strict.

Assume we have an eps file with the width `width_eps` and the height `height_eps`. The maximum possible width and height above those the image is cropped are `width_max` and `height_max`, respectively. Unfortunately, we have `width_eps > width_max`. But, if `width_eps < height_max` and `height_eps < width_max` we

- rotate our eps file outside of latex (a create it rotated) and
- include it with the option `angle=-90` or `angle=90` (code posted above).

Yes, the solution is useless if `width_eps > height_max` or `height_eps > width_max`